# Windows process exit notification sent with resources still held

Tags: c, windows, process, io-completion-ports

I am debugging a problem in a build system which is essentially doing the following:

1. A parent spawns a child process.
2. The child process creates a file and exits without closing the handle.
3. The parent waits on [JOB_OBJECT_MSG_EXIT_PROCESS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winnt/ns-winnt-jobobject_associate_completion_port) for the child to exit.
4. The parent attempts to open the file created by the child. This fails with ERROR_SHARING_VIOLATION.

[Windows Performance Analyzer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/test/wpt/windows-performance-analyzer) tracing shows that the open attempt occurs after the child process lifetime has ended yet while file cleanup is still ongoing.

In this zombie state the process handle is not yet signaled and blocking with [WaitForSingleObject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/synchapi/nf-synchapi-waitforsingleobject) resolves the race.

The behavior is consistent across several Windows 10/11 systems, including with antivirus disabled. This is surprising to me and seems to limit the value of [JOB_OBJECT_MSG_EXIT_PROCESS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winnt/ns-winnt-jobobject_associate_completion_port) notifications.

Does Windows have a process state where processes have exited with API-visible side effects still ongoing? If so, is waiting for the process handle to be signaled required to reliably wait for this zombie state to finish?

(Waiting for [JOB_OBJECT_MSG_ACTIVE_PROCESS_ZERO](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winnt/ns-winnt-jobobject_associate_completion_port) also appears to be sufficient yet is not useful in this application.)

---

```c
/**
 * Repro case demonstrating resources held after JOB_OBJECT_MSG_EXIT_PROCESS
 */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>

// Test condition and panic out after tracing the offending line number on error
#define CHECK(cond) (check_at((cond), __LINE__))
static void check_at(_Bool cond, unsigned int line) {
    if(!cond) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s:%u: failed\n", __FILE__, line);
        ExitProcess(1);
    }
}

// Operate as child process create the file and leave cleaning up to the OS
static void child(const WCHAR filename[]) {
    HANDLE handle = CreateFileW(filename, GENERIC_WRITE, FILE_SHARE_READ, NULL,
        CREATE_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
    CHECK(handle != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE);
    static const char payload[0x10000 /* ≥5 bytes required */];
    DWORD written;
    CHECK(WriteFile(handle, payload, sizeof payload, &written, NULL));
    CHECK(written == sizeof payload);
}

// Operate as parent executing the child and waiting for completion before
// accessing the file
static const char *parent(const WCHAR filename[], WCHAR app_name[], BOOL poll) {
    // Use job object reporting status to an I/O completion port to wait for exit.
    // Plain WaitForSingleObject on the child fails to reproduce the issue
    HANDLE job = CreateJobObjectW(NULL, NULL);
    CHECK(job);
    HANDLE iocp = CreateIoCompletionPort(INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE, NULL, 0, 0);
    CHECK(iocp);
    JOBOBJECT_ASSOCIATE_COMPLETION_PORT assoc = { .CompletionPort = iocp };
    CHECK(SetInformationJobObject(job,
        JobObjectAssociateCompletionPortInformation, &assoc, sizeof assoc));

    // Associate job with queue immediately from startup (Windows ≥10 required)
    STARTUPINFOEXW si = { .StartupInfo.cb = sizeof si };
    size_t space = 0;
    while(!InitializeProcThreadAttributeList(si.lpAttributeList, 1, 0, &space))
        si.lpAttributeList = _alloca(space);
    DWORD proc_attrib = 0x0002000DU /* PROC_THREAD_ATTRIBUTE_JOB_LIST */;
    CHECK(UpdateProcThreadAttribute(si.lpAttributeList, 0, proc_attrib, &job,
        sizeof job, NULL, NULL));

    // Pass a second dummy command line argument to trigger child behavior
    WCHAR command_line[] = L"dummy recurse";
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
    CHECK(CreateProcessW(app_name, command_line, NULL, NULL, TRUE,
        EXTENDED_STARTUPINFO_PRESENT, NULL, NULL, &si.StartupInfo, &pi));

    // Wait for successful process to exit
    DWORD event;
    OVERLAPPED *overlapped;
    do {
        ULONG_PTR key;
        CHECK(GetQueuedCompletionStatus(iocp, &event, &key, &overlapped, INFINITE));
    } while(event != JOB_OBJECT_MSG_EXIT_PROCESS &&
        event != JOB_OBJECT_MSG_ABNORMAL_EXIT_PROCESS);
    CHECK((ULONG_PTR) overlapped == pi.dwProcessId);

    // Poll and verify yet to be signaled or block until signaled
    if(poll)
        CHECK(WaitForSingleObject(pi.hProcess, 0) != WAIT_OBJECT_0);
    else
        CHECK(WaitForSingleObject(pi.hProcess, INFINITE) == WAIT_OBJECT_0);

    // Verify successful exit
    DWORD exit_code;
    CHECK(GetExitCodeProcess(pi.hProcess, &exit_code));
    CHECK(exit_code == 0);

    // Try to read the expected output file
    HANDLE handle = CreateFileW(filename, GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ, NULL,
        OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
    if(handle != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
        CHECK(CloseHandle(handle));
        return "PASS";
    } else {
        CHECK(GetLastError() == ERROR_SHARING_VIOLATION);
        return "FAIL";
    }
}

int wmain(int argc, WCHAR *argv[]) {
    const WCHAR *filename = L"shared_file";
    if(argc == 1) {
        printf("polling:  %s\n", parent(filename, argv[0], TRUE));
        printf("blocking: %s\n", parent(filename, argv[0], FALSE));
    } else {
        child(filename);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: destroying of process is complex. many things is doint during this. one - is sent `JOB_OBJECT_MSG_EXIT_PROCESS` if process in job and have associated port. another task - close all opend handles (destroy process handle table). probably destroy process handle table is done after job notify. as result you can got it before handles will be closed

Comment: @RbMm: I see. Do you know if these semantics are documented anywhere? I guess the notification is only intended for use in determining the exit status and should not be used in I/O multiplexing to wait for the other effects of the process then?

Comment: this of course not documented and internal implementation. probably wait on process object will be the best, but even this can not on 100% guarantee that you not got share violation if try open file immediatelly after child exit. use WaitForSingleObject only one possible implementation. also possible CreateThreadpoolWait + SetThreadpoolWait . in this case not thread wait on object (process) but special completion packet allocated, and when object signaled - this packed inserted to iocp and your callback called (or even direct NtCreateWaitCompletionPacket + NtAssociateWaitCompletionPacket)

Comment: @RbMm: So you are saying that waiting on the process handle may also be unreliable but that this is the best that can be done? Perhaps this all warrants an answer? Anyway, I never knew about the nifty `NtAssociateWaitCompletionPacket`.

Comment: A more careful reading also revealed the caveat: [Note that, except for limits set with the JobObjectNotificationLimitInformation information class, messages are intended only as notifications and their delivery to the completion port is not guaranteed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/job-objects). It would seems that job object notifications have very limited use and should usually be avoided.

Comment: *So you are saying that waiting on the process handle may also be unreliable but that this is the best that can be done* - not sure. may be very short time, after handle closed, it pointer can be still hold by cache or something else. It seems that I once encountered something similar a long time ago - I tried to delete the exe immediately after its process was completed, and this caused an error, but with a any delay everything was ok. but I don't remember exactly. the CompletionPacket is alternative way for wait on some object - instead hold thread - got packet to iocp

Answer (score 0):

Guess #1:  Maybe the file isn't closed and released until the child process is cleaned up.  Even though the child process has completed, the parent process still holds an open handle.  (The `PROCESS_INFORMATION` structure filled out in the call to `CreateProcess` has handles to the child process and its primary thread.)  Have the parent close the child process handles before attempting to open the file.

Guess #2:  Anti-malware software saw the creation of a new file and opened it with a lock until it scans it.

Comment: Sadly closing the handles in the parent prior opening the file does not help, I omitted these steps for brevity. Deferring cleanup until after all handles to a child process are closed would seem to imply an inherent race with more than one processes waiting on the same child, since there would be no way of knowing how long to wait after you released your handle until all other waiting process released theirs.

Comment: I tried to disable all anti-virus software and test across multiple computers with different protection when running the test. There was also no apparent trace of such activity in the Windows Performance Analyzer traces afterwards, though it is admittedly difficult to conclusively prove a negative here.